# How to Update HTML from ext script with Unique Id when ItemId not there in component

Tags: extjs

I am updating some HTML from ext script.
I used to do below steps to do DOM manipulation:

```
var newid = Ext.getCmp('button-1064');
var newitemid = newid.itemId
getComponent(newitemid).setStyle('height', '437px');
```

But now I don't have itemId in component (newid.itemId)

Comment: use directly `Ext.getCmp('button-1064').setStyle()`

Comment: @yogesh: You mean that component is not having ID, so cannot access itemId ? Can you please explain problem you are facing

Comment: In extjs it will give different ID's each time when it's loaded

Comment: @tejas,  yes exactly

Comment: @YOGEESH yes because it auto generated id

Comment: @YOGEESH If you want to access your component then you can provide itemId or name or any other config to get component.

Comment: Not necessary.We can get component by other means also.I will share fiddle regarding same

Comment: @Jadav, so is there any solution?

Comment: @YOGEESH Provide more details exactly what you need ?

Comment: @Tejas   getComponent(newid.name).setStyle('height', '437px'); will be unique..? it wont any other HTML element are you sure

Comment: its provided @Jadav

Comment: @YOGEESH check this [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/295b)  this will guide you

Comment: @YOGEESH you can check https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2h7i&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

You can tryed with "[reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Container.html#cfg-reference)" attribute and the function "[lookupReference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-lookupReference)" like this :

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    reference: 'myBtn',
    [...]
}

var object = this.lookupReference('myBtn');
object.setStyle([...]);
```